# Can I have users of my PHP/SQL/HTML/Javascript application login through my windows domain controller

Tags: php, domaincontroller

I currently have an application I have built that the users login by retrieving the username and password from a MS SQL table with user info, we were thinking that once we implement a Windows Server Domain Controller, it would be better to let the sever do the authentication part rather than storing it in the database and comparing login info there and just passing back a true or false if the login was successful.

Is this possible or should we stick with the PHP SQL method?

Comment: It is possible, however what you should do depends on a lot of different things. So it's a bit hard to answer your question. - Ref: [Using LDAPS with PHP on Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/589454/using-ldaps-with-php-on-windows)

Comment: I prefer this tutorial (as it helped me understand the process) to the straight up PHP manual for this, if you want to answer I'll give you the vote if not I'll vote for @Aivar Luist

Comment: Then please close your question as an dupicate or just close it. All I did was searching this up on Stackoverflow network, if that now suites your needs, you have obviously not looked before. So I won't answer because it is not a real question.

Comment: good work you win, I love the description in the 'closed as not a real question' box below, "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened" but you did answer my question, you didn't seem to have any trouble understanding as you gave me a perfect answer, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php ldap for that.
[ldap](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php)